# How do I create a floating window in Android 10?

Tags: java, android, permissions, android-permissions, permission-denied

I'm trying to create a floating window for Android, but all the possible ways need permissions to draw over the other apps.

This appears when I try to get the permission in Android 10, Core M01.

[image]

Comment: I notice that Samsung Core M01's OS is Android 10 (Go edition), maybe go edition don't support? https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_m01_core-10316.php

Comment: i dont know, i can use window manager type ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE to make floating window, but its not good.